# Switch twocolumn between right-to-left and left-to-right with the package multiind in polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, arabic, right-to-left

Writing a book in arabic, I want to obtain a dictionnary of used words in my document between arabic and english, and want that the entries of the dictionnary will be in two different orders, in arabic alphabetic order and in english alphabetic order. My idea is to use the package multiind which produces several indexes, to produce two idx files `dic_english.idx` and `dic_arabic.idx`.

The commands

```
\index{dic_english}{Random@\idxsechead{Random\hfill arabic_word}|idxnopage}
```

and

```
\index{dic_arabic}{arabic_word@\idxsechead{Random\hfill arabic_word}|idxnopage}
```

will produce these two files, the same files, in english order for the first and arabic order for the second. My problem is that the twocolumn command will produce columnation on the right for the two files (first column on the right and second on the left)... but I want to obtain the index in english order having the first column on the left and the second column on the right. Someone have some idea for this ?... Precisely, How can I obtain an index right-to-left and an index left-to-right in the same time?

Thanks, Faouzi

Comment: Could you please add a fully compilable minimum (working) example to illustrate and support your situation? It is helping solvers a lot.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your interest. I post an example... The letters أ, ب, ت are (in right to left sense) the 3 first letters of arabic alphabet... I associate for this example a with ب, b with ت  , and c with أ. the two indexes are written in the two orders, but in right-to-left for the two, and I want the english index in left-to-right sense, i.e. that the first column be in the left not in the right. I post in an answer. Thank you

Comment: Note that I post it with all the packages used in my book..

Comment: Oh, but please put it in your original post (if you can edit it), not as an answer. There is also a tip for you: if you insert four spaces in front of a source code line, then that line will be typeset as a source code.

Comment: For solvers: we use [`imakeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) these days for that task, [`multind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multind) is an old package, if we want to get it, we could use `wget http://ftp.cstug.cz/pub/tex/CTAN/macros/latex209/contrib/misc/multind.sty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}%{article}%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fmultico}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}
\usepackage{multind}
\makeindex{dico-english}
\makeindex{dico-arabic}
%%%  OBTAIN INDEX WITHOUT NUMBERS OF PAGE   %%%%%
\newcommand{\idxnopage}[1]{{}}
\providecommand{\gobble}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\idxsechead}[1]{#1\gobble}
\begin{document}
\index{dico-english}{c@\idxsechead{أ\hfill c}|idxnopage}
\index{dico-english}{a@\idxsechead{ب\hfill a}|idxnopage}
\index{dico-english}{b@\idxsechead{ت\hfill b}|idxnopage}
\index{dico-arabic}{أ@\idxsechead{أ\hfill c}|idxnopage}
\index{dico-arabic}{ب@\idxsechead{ب\hfill a}|idxnopage}
\index{dico-arabic}{ت@\idxsechead{ت\hfill b}|idxnopage}

\printindex{dico-english}{\LR{English entries...}}
\printindex{dico-arabic}{\LR{Arabic entries...}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I omitted to say that the index file dico-arabic.ind is generated by the dos-command makeindex dico-arabic.idx, and by the same for the dico-english index... Sorry ..

Comment: Thanks for posting this code which, I assume, is meant to augment your original posting. Would you mind providing a bit of an explanation what the code is supposed to do or illustrate?

Comment: The key problem is that once we load `\setmainlanguage{arabic}` (part of the `polyglossia` package) the flow of columns in two-column regime is from right to left, but the English index should be typeset as we know it: from left to the right column. After downloading the `multind` package and commenting out the `slashbox` package, the code is running. I believe there is another issue and that's sorting of Arabic terms, `makeindex` is not capable of handling that directly to my best knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to change the page column layouts using the [`flowfram`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) package, but it's quite complicated. The example below starts with a single column layout for the title page and first two chapters, then switches to a LR two column layout for the third chapter, followed by a RL two column layout for the fourth chapter and then switches back to a single column layout for the final two chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\newlength\chapheadheight
\setlength\chapheadheight{0.25\textheight}

\newlength\chapflowheight
\setlength\chapflowheight{\textheight-\chapheadheight}

\newdynamicframe[none]{\textwidth}{\chapheadheight}{0pt}{\chapflowheight}[chaphead]

\dfchaphead*{chaphead}

\newflowframe[none]{\textwidth}{\chapflowheight}{0pt}{0pt}[chapmain]

\onecolumn
\setflowframe{2}{label=main}

\twocolumninarea[none]{\textwidth}{\chapflowheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\setflowframe{3}{label=chap-english-left}
\setflowframe{4}{label=chap-english-right}

\twocolumn[none]
\setflowframe{5}{label=english-left}
\setflowframe{6}{label=english-right}

\lefttorightcolumnsfalse

\twocolumninarea[none]{\textwidth}{\chapflowheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\setflowframe{7}{label=chap-arabic-right}
\setflowframe{8}{label=chap-arabic-left}

\twocolumn[none]
\setflowframe{9}{label={arabic-right}}
\setflowframe{10}{label={arabic-left}}

\newcommand*{\prechaphook}{%
  \dynamicswitchonnextoddonly*{chaphead}%
  \flowswitchonnextoddonly*{chapmain}%
  \flowswitchoffnextoddonly*{main}%
}

\preto\chapter{\prechaphook}

\newcommand*{\switchonLRtwocolumns}{%
  \flowswitchonnext*{english-left,english-right}%
  \flowswitchoffnext*{chapmain,main}%
  \dynamicswitchonnextoddonly*{chaphead}%
  \flowswitchonnextoddonly*{chap-english-left,chap-english-right}%
  \flowswitchoffnextoddonly*{english-left,english-right}%
  \cleardoublepage
  \renewcommand*{\prechaphook}{}%
}

\newcommand*{\switchonRLtwocolumns}{%
  \flowswitchonnext*{arabic-left,arabic-right}%
  \flowswitchoffnext*{english-left,english-right}%
  \dynamicswitchonnextoddonly*{chaphead}%
  \flowswitchonnextoddonly*{chap-arabic-left,chap-arabic-right}%
  \flowswitchoffnextoddonly*{arabic-left,arabic-right}%
  \cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand*{\switchononecolumn}{%
  \flowswitchoffnext*{arabic-left,arabic-right}%
  \flowswitchonnext*{main}%
  \dynamicswitchonnextoddonly*{chaphead}%
  \flowswitchonnextoddonly*{chapmain}%
  \flowswitchoffnextoddonly*{main}%
  \clearpage
  \renewcommand*{\prechaphook}{%
    \renewcommand*{\prechaphook}{%
       \dynamicswitchonnextoddonly*{chaphead}%
       \flowswitchonnextoddonly*{chapmain}%
       \flowswitchoffnextoddonly*{main}%
    }%
  }%
}

\title{Sample Title}
\author{Sample Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Sample}
\lipsum

\chapter{Another Sample}
\lipsum[1-5]

\switchonLRtwocolumns
\chapter{LR}
\lipsum

\switchonRLtwocolumns
\chapter{RL}
\lipsum

\switchononecolumn
\chapter{One Column Again}

\lipsum

\chapter{And Again}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This assumes a two-sided book. You may need to set a larger value for `\chapheadheight` if your chapter headings exceed the allocated space. You should be able to just replace `\chapter{LR}` with the `\printindex{dico-english}` command and replace `\chapter{RL}` with the `\printindex{dico-arabic}{\LR{Arabic entries...}}` command. (I don't have the required fonts installed to compile your example.)

**Edit**:

If you want to use `polyglossia` with `flowfram` you have to make sure you load `polyglossia` first, as they both modify the output routine.

Comment: Hello, I saw, in a first try, that these commands superposes several pages on the others and I don't know why.. I see it in detail today... Thank you

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Does this happen with the example I gave in my answer or when you modify the example? If it's with this example, can you give the `flowfram` version number, otherwise you'll need to post a MWE illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you this solution. As long as you don't have clickable version of index page numbers in indices we can separate creation of English index. I created a new file containing only preamble of the document to preserve design and layout of the original document.

The key change is in swapping the `\setmainlanguage` and `\setotherlanguage` commands which can be set in the preamble only. The new file (`mal-english.pdf`) is then cropped and included back to the main file (`mal-arabic.tex`). I usually use `\pdfximage` and `\pdflastximagepages` to get number of pages of included PDF file, but these pdfTeX primitives are not supported in XeLaTeX. Therefore, I used `\XeTeXpdfpagecount` for this task and it works smoothly.

I tried to add several more terms to your dictionary, please excuse me if I misspelled or mishandled some Arabic terms. I believe that you have another problem to solve because `makeindex` cannot sort complex languages directly to my best knowledge. Moreover, `xindy` can handle complex languages but it doesn't support Arabic either, at least it is not offered in the official distribution in TeX Live (2013).

I've also programmed a new command named `\aeindex` and it saves terms to both indices by interchanging two parameters. It should save you some time.

I run these commands to get English-Arabic and Arabic-English indices in one PDF file. Please bear in mind that `makeindex dico-arabic.idx` must be replaced by better tool. It is likely you already know what kind of tool you need (a tool from ArabTeX, ArabXeTeX or ConTeXt, perhaps?). It might be the case of `makeindex dico-english.idx` too, because English terms could occur several times and you would need sorting according to the Arabic sorting rules.

> xelatex mal-arabic.tex
>   makeindex dico-arabic.idx
>   makeindex dico-english.idx
>   xelatex mal-english.tex
>   pdfcrop --hires mal-english.pdf
>   xelatex mal-arabic.tex

The first command stores the index entries into two files, those files are then processed by `makeindex`, then we get English index as a standalone PDF file, which is cropped and included back to the main TeX file.

I enclose three TeX files (preamble for both documents, main Arabic file and an English index) and a preview of typesetted two pages.

The `mal-arabic-preamble.tex` file:

```
%! I am mal-arabic-preamble.tex...
%! Don't run me directly...
%
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}
%{article}%
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{boxedminipage}
%\usepackage{slashbox}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{minitoc}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{fmultico} \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} \pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight=17pt
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multind} 
\makeindex{dico-english} 
\makeindex{dico-arabic}
%%% OBTAIN INDEX WITHOUT NUMBERS OF PAGE %%%%%
\newcommand{\idxnopage}[1]{{}} % This line deletes index page number.
\providecommand{\gobble}[1]{{}} % This line deletes a comma.
\newcommand{\idxsechead}[1]{#1\gobble}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\def\RLarabic#1{\selectlanguage{arabic}\RL{#1}\selectlanguage{english}}

\def\aeindex#1#2{%
  \index{dico-english}{#2@\string\idxsechead{#2\hfill\RLarabic{#1}}|idxnopage}%
  \index{dico-arabic}{#1@\string\idxsechead{#1\hfill\LR{#2}}|idxnopage}%
  }% End of \aeindex...
```

The `mal-arabic.tex` file:

```
%! xelatex mal-arabic.tex
\input{mal-arabic-preamble.tex}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri} 
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}%1.0
\begin{document}
% Arabic--English index...
\aeindex{أ}{c}%
\aeindex{ب}{a}%
\aeindex{ت}{b}%
% http://www.lexilogos.com/english/arabic_dictionary.htm
\aeindex{ذاتَ اليَمِين}{to the right}
\aeindex{بُرتُقال ( نب )}{orange}
\aeindex{أُوتُومُوبِيل}{car}
\aeindex{تَشرِيعِيّ}{house}
\aeindex{مَحضَرُ ضَبطِ سَير}{ticket}
\aeindex{كَوكَب سَيّار}{planet}
\aeindex{مُستَحكَم}{serious}

% An old approach
%\printindex{dico-english}{\LR{English entries...}}
% One experiment...
\def\englishname{\LR{English entries...}}
\markright {\uppercase {\englishname}} 
\addcontentsline {toc}{section}{\englishname}
\def\malname{mal-english-crop.pdf}%
\newcount\malcounter \malcounter=0%
\loop
\newpage
\advance\malcounter by 1
\hfill\includegraphics[page={\the\malcounter}]{\malname}% or
% A manual cropping in case pdfcrop doesn't work...
% viewport=2.35cm 4.5cm 17.4cm 25.3cm, clip 
\ifnum\malcounter<\XeTeXpdfpagecount{\malname}\repeat % Number of pages of mal-english.pdf file...

\printindex{dico-arabic}{\LR{Arabic entries...}}
\end{document}
```

And this is the `mal-english.tex` file:

```
%! xelatex mal-english.tex
\input{mal-arabic-preamble.tex}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri} 
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri} % 1.5
\begin{document}
\printindex{dico-english}{\LR{English entries...}}
\end{document}
```

This is a preview of the `mal-arabic.pdf` file:

[image: mwe]

Comment: Hello,your macro is very ingenious..switching between english and arabic by this way gives the solution... I try it on my files and publish it. Thanks a lot. Faouzi

Comment: And what I'm laughing about is the arabic words that you use.... from a translation's software !?

Comment: Oh yes, yes, I hoped we could have a little fun. :-) Actually the terms are from http://www.lexilogos.com/english/arabic_dictionary.htm, but from time to time I copied only portion of each line...

Comment: Thank you for your compliments, but I believe there could be a better solution as we only need to move index terms (line by line) from one column to the other. For instance, we use `\makebox` for that purpose but we need to know if we are typesetting in the first or in the second column to jump properly, let me think about it...

Comment: Hello, Ok for some other genious idea..it's not a compliment.. Thanks

Comment: Hello, There's two problems in my files.. The first... is that when I do the command prompt pdfcrop ... mal-english.ind, I obtain the message "The Perl interpreter could not be found", usual for the adaptation from Linux programs... I have solved it by changing, in your program the name of the file (from mal-english-crop.pdf to mal-english.pdf)...

Comment: A second thing, and more serious, is that the first index (english text) jumps a page... i.e. puts first a blank page, after, in the second page it puts  vertical and horizontal spaces in the page 2, and then if there's a second column (which is the case) it splits very out the (right) margin...because it begins very far in the right of the left margin

Comment: Please try manual cropping in the main TeX file, change `\hfill\includegraphics[page={\the\malcounter}]{\malname}` to `\hfill\includegraphics[page={\the\malcounter}, viewport=2.35cm 4.5cm 17.4cm 25.3cm, clip]{\malname}`. Those two problems are related: including a non-cropped version of PDF file results in adding an empty page and shifted in addition to that.

Comment: Here comes another problem with manual cropping. If you start using `twoside` option in the `\documentclass` this manual cropping (as it is) will work only for odd or even pages. It would need a fix. But it can be done, if needed. About `pdfcrop`, it needs Perl to be installed, if I remember that well.

Comment: Many thks for your so pedagogic explanation... I have another problem.. For example, The too long entries like

 \aeindex{كثيرات الحدود، مبرهنة}{Multinomial, theorem}

produce absolutely not beautiful entries in the index... I solve it on the .ind files...for example, on dico-english.ind, I replace the entry

Comment: I guess you need one-column regime, is that right? :-)

Comment: It would solve all the problems to have one column there, because we could use the same design for both indices: English on left, Arabic terms on the right side.

Comment: The common solution is to use `\small` or `\footnotesize` or other method of scaling text at the beginning of the indices. But text is becoming worse for reading.

Comment: Yes it would solve all the problems ..but not very beautiful... and it will take a strong place... How can I put the index in one column in multind package ??... The option [columns=1] fail, I think !

Comment: I replace the  long entry in the .ind file

  \item \idxsechead{Multinomial, theorem\hfill \selectlanguage {arabic}\RL {كثيرات الحدود، مبرهنة}\selectlanguage {english}}, 
  \idxnopage{15} 
  
  by the entry
 \item \idxsechead{\begin{tabular}{cc}
\LR{Multinomial,}&\selectlanguage {arabic}\RL{كثيرات الحدود،}\selectlanguage {english} \\
\LR{theorem}&\selectlanguage {arabic} مبرهنة\selectlanguage {english} 
  \end{tabular}}, \idxnopage{15}

it produces some beautiful text...

Comment: The `multind` package is quite old, please check if you could use the `imakeidx` package. There are fine options, including `columns=1`.

Comment: Yes.. for columns=1..what do you think about a macro producing tabular indices...?

Comment: something like...

\def\ae2index#1#2#3#4{%
  \index{mydico-english}{#3@\string\idxsechead{\begin{tabular}{cc}
\LR{#3,}&\selectlanguage {arabic}\RL{#1،}\selectlanguage {english} \\
\LR{#4}&\selectlanguage {arabic} #2\selectlanguage {english} 
  \end{tabular}}|idxnopage}%
  }% End of \ae2index...

Comment: something producing entries of index in two lines....

Comment: You can use `\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{4cm}}` or similar dimensions and in that command two parameters/terms would be enough. It is an option. I think we cannot use digit in the name of the command directly.

Comment: It is worth experimenting. Try to prepare longer index and you will see if this method is working well for you.

Comment: I personally would prefer one column with leading dots in the middle (the similar layout as we can see in the table of contents) resulting in having one term per one line. Well, don't take my word for it, try it your way!

Comment: Something like this ??

\def\aeindex_TAB#1#2{%
  \index{mydico-english}{#2@\string\idxsechead{
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{4cm}}  
\LR{#2,}&\selectlanguage {arabic}\RL{#1،}\selectlanguage {english} 
  \end{tabular}}|idxnopage}%
  }% End of \aeindex_TAB...

Comment: There would be a problem with the underscore, try `\def\tindex#1#2`...

Comment: Ok.. not for the name... it's my choice...Ok for Taeindex for example... for the synthax of Latex... what do you think about the commands ?

Comment: It looks fine, the important thing is that you are going to use it frequently, it must fit your needs.

Comment: I must say that it doesn't matter if you feed the `tabular` with one or two lines of text, you can simply define it as `\aeindex...` as before.

Comment: In compilation.. I have the message Tex capacity exceeded...

I put the entry 

 \Taeindex{كثيرات الحدود\\مبرهنة}{Multinomial\\theorem}

Comment: The macro in preambule is 

\def\Taeindex#1#2{%
  \index{mydico-english}{#2@\string\idxsechead{
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{4cm}}  
\LR{#2,}&\selectlanguage {arabic}\RL{#1،}\selectlanguage {english} 
  \end{tabular}}|idxnopage}%
  }% End of \Taeindex...

Comment: The `tabular` environment is handling the breaks, please delete those two backslashes.

Comment: If I delete the backslashes, How can I specify the lines of the tabular in this case ?

Comment: The entry 

\Taeindex{كثيرات الحدود\\مبرهنة}{Multinomial\\theorem}

means for me 

..first line... كثيرات الحدود....Multinomial

...second line... مبرهنة... theorem

Comment: It is done automatically. `tabular` is typesetting text into given dimension.

Comment: I  still have the message...

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\bidi@csuse #1->\ifcsname #1
                            \endcsname \csname #1\expandafter \endcsname \fi 
l.237 ...دود مبرهنة}{Multinomial theorem}

Comment: Ah, you changed `dico-english` to `mydico`, I am not able to reproduce this error for now. For time being I would try different index: Arabic term (English term), and, English term (Arabic term).

Comment: Excuse me I have not seen the command... I have changed for my own files... Thanks for your interest..

Comment: I have different error when including `tabular`, so let's skip it for now.

Comment: Hello, I want to ask you about the width of the page (and then the width of the columns) which is, for th english index, lesser then the columnwidth of the arabic index. Why is it the case ?.. Thank you

Comment: It is a bit surprise to me, I guess it is worth another question here at TeX.SX with some example/sample from you in the post.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to operate the migration to the imakeidx package, which will not be easy, because of the difference of syntaxes... [] instead of {}... The first try appears beautiful and more powerful...with some bugs... but...what a great surprise !!!... It uses automatically the arabic alphabet for arabic entries and english for english entries...  I think that it will be a very beautiful macro... I inform you when I advance a little in my tries... Thank you...

Comment: @Faouzi This is my other proposal to you problem which I had in mind earlier: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172019/how-can-we-swap-columns-in-two-column-regime-preserving-hyperlinks

Answer (score 1):

Its worth it to mention the commands `\RTLdblcol` and `\LTRdblcol`; for more details see section 1.10 of `bidi` package documentation on page 11.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\RTLdblcol
\section{Right to left columns}
\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage
\LTRdblcol
\section{Left to right columns}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Please, show how exactly the commands can be used to solve the problem in the question. Without the complete solution, the answer carries too little information to be useful.

Comment: @tohecz: I added an example; if you still think that it is not good enough, please let me know so that I can edit the answer.

Comment: Well, the question reads "with the package multiind in polyglossia", I don't see any of them in your answer, nor a solution that would do the same thing without them.

Comment: Well, I give hints; I think with my hint it is easy to know what should one do; on the other hand polyglossia loads bidi for RTL.

Comment: Hello everybody. I just saw your comments...the command \LTRdblcol seems to solve my problem... I will apply this on my multi index problem, and inform you about the feasibility of it... Many thanks

Comment: @Faouzi Yes, please do with a full example included, I am also interested if that is already implemented there. It looks it is, but I cannot test it right now.

Comment: @Malpivo I promise that I'll do it very soon... I'm full of work, retrieving the last version of my book.. I do this all the time.. Many Thanks but the commands \LTR... \RTL... seems very very well...we can compile this and implement a beautiful macro I think...

Comment: @Malpivo I've done another try with the \LTR options... It seems good.. But the title of the english dico remains on the right, and the column begins with a reverse first entry !! (arabic entry on the left and english on the right)... I post an example the files

Answer (score 0):

```
    The preamble file Preamble.tex %%%

    \documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr} \pagestyle{fancy}
    \headheight=17pt
    \usepackage{multind} 
    \makeindex{EN} 
    \makeindex{AR} 
    %%% OBTAIN INDEX WITHOUT NUMBERS OF PAGE %%%%%
    \newcommand{\idxnopage}[1]{{}} % This line deletes index page number.
    \providecommand{\gobble}[1]{{}} % This line deletes a comma.
    \newcommand{\idxsechead}[1]{#1\gobble}
    \usepackage{polyglossia} 
    \def\RLarabic#1{\selectlanguage{arabic}\RL{#1}\selectlanguage{english}}

    \def\aeindex#1#2{%
      \index{EN}{#2@\string\idxsechead{#2\hfill\RLarabic{#1}}|idxnopage}%
      \index{AR}{#1@\string\idxsechead{#1\hfill\LR{#2}}|idxnopage}%
      }% End of \aeindex...

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    THE FILE

    \input{Preamble.tex}

    \setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic} 
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri} 
    \setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}%1.0
    \begin{document}
    \aeindex{أ}{c}%
    \aeindex{ب}{a}%
    \aeindex{ت}{b}%
    \aeindex{ذاتَ اليَمِين}{to the right}
    \aeindex{بُرتُقال ( نب )}{orange}
    \aeindex{أُوتُومُوبِيل}{car}
    \aeindex{تَشرِيعِيّ}{house}
    \aeindex{مَحضَرُ ضَبطِ سَير}{ticket}
    \aeindex{كَوكَب سَيّار}{planet}
    \aeindex{مُستَحكَم}{serious}
    \aeindex{عداد}{counter}

    \RTLdblcol
    \printindex{AR}{\LR{Arabic entries...}}
    \LTRdblcol
    \printindex{EN}{\LR{English entries...}}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I give here the answer of the problem of using indices for making dictionnaries, thanks to this very powerful discussion... I post all, with all the entries, to share the dictionnary with who interest with it... and I want to call you to tell me some websites where I could share it, in the pdf-form, for the scientists working with probability in arabic ... I have also two questions about this, and I will talk about it after giving the whole file, with the entries used...

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}%{article}%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{slashbox}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fmultico}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

 \usepackage{multind}
\makeindex{dico-arabic} 
\makeindex{dico-english} 





%%% OBTAIN INDEX WITHOUT NUMBERS OF PAGE %%%%%
\newcommand{\idxnopage}[1]{{}} % This line deletes index page number.
\providecommand{\gobble}[1]{{}} % This line deletes a comma.
\newcommand{\idxsechead}[1]{#1\gobble}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\def\RLarabic#1{\selectlanguage{arabic}\RL{#1}\selectlanguage{english}}

\def\aeindex#1#2#3#4{%
  \index{dico-english}{#3@\string\idxsechead{#4\hfill\RLarabic{#2}}|idxnopage}%
  \index{dico-arabic}{#1@\string\idxsechead{#2\hfill\LR{#4}}|idxnopage}%
  }% End of \aeindex...


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   INDEX ENTRIES   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\aeindex{دالة متصلة}{دالة متصلة}{Continuous function}{Continuous function}
\aeindex{دالة احتمالية}{دالة احتمالية}{Probability}{Probability}
\aeindex{إحداثيات ديكارتية}{الإحداثيات الديكارتية}{Cartesian coordinates}{Cartesian coordinates}
\aeindex{إحداثيات قطبية}{الإحداثيات القطبية}{Polar coordinates}{Polar coordinates}

\aeindex{متباينة بوول}{متباينة بوول}{Boole's inequality}{Boole's inequality}

\aeindex{متباينة}{متباينة}{Inequality}{Inequality}


\aeindex{قانون إحتواء-الإبعاد}{قانون الإحتواء-الإبعاد}{Inclusion-exclusion identity}{Inclusion-exclusion identity}



\aeindex{زهرة نرد}{زهرة نرد}{Dice}{Dice}
\aeindex{قابل للقياس}{قابل للقياس}{Measurable}{Measurable}
\aeindex{فراغ العينة}{فراغ العينة}{Sample space}{Sample space}

\aeindex{أشكال فن}{أشكال فن}{Venn Diagram}{Venn Diagram}
\aeindex{قوانين إبدالية}{القوانين الإبدالية}{Commutative laws}{Commutative laws}
\aeindex{قوانين تجميعية}{القوانين التجميعية}{Associative laws}{Associative laws}
\aeindex{قوانين توزيعية}{القوانين التوزيعية}{Associative laws}{Associative laws}
\aeindex{قوانين دي مورجن}{قوانين دي مورجن}{DeMorgan's laws}{DeMorgan's laws}

\aeindex{مستقلة}{مستقلة}{Independant}{Independant}
\aeindex{محاولات}{محاولات}{Trials}{Trials}
\aeindex{رسم بياني تام}{رسم بياني تام}{Complete graph}{Complete graph}
\aeindex{أحادي الزيجوت}{أحادي الزيجوت}{Monozygotic}{Monozygotic}
\aeindex{ثنائي الزيجوت}{ثنائي الزيجوت}{Dizygotic}{Dizygotic}
\aeindex{حصرية}{حصرية}{Exhaustive}{Exhaustive}
\aeindex{قانون ضرب}{قانون الضرب}{Multiplication rule}{Multiplication rule}
\aeindex{متساوية}{متساوية}{Equality}{Equality}
\aeindex{مقدر الاحتمال الأعظم}{مقدر الاحتمال الأعظم}{Maximum likelihood estimate}{Maximum likelihood estimate}
\aeindex{توزيع زيتا}{زيتا}{Distribution Zeta}{Zeta}
\aeindex{توزيع بواسون}{بواسون}{distribution Poisson's}{Poisson's}
\aeindex{توزيع برنوللي}{برنوللي}{distribution Bernoulli's}{Bernoulli's}
\aeindex{عزم الجمود}{عزم الجمود}{Moment of inertia}{Moment of inertia}
\aeindex{مبرهنة فوبيني}{مبرهنة فوبيني}{Fubini's theorem}{Fubini's theorem}
\aeindex{متغير مؤشّر}{متغير مؤشّر}{Indicator variable}{Indicator variable}
\aeindex{مركز الثقل}{مركز الثقل}{Center of gravity}{Center of gravity}
\aeindex{مجموعة منفصلة}{مجموعة منفصلة}{Discrete set}{Discrete set}
\aeindex{مجموعة تعدادية}{مجموعة تعدادية}{Countable set}{Countable set}
\aeindex{متغير عشوائي}{متغير عشوائي}{Random variable}{Random variable}
\aeindex{دالة رتيبة}{دالة رتيبة}{Strictly monotonic function}{Strictly monotonic function}
\aeindex{توزيع جاما}{جاما}{Distribution Gamma}{Gamma}
\aeindex{منتظمة التقارب}{منتظمة التقارب}{Uniformly convergent}{Uniformly convergent}
\aeindex{توزيع فايبل}{فايبل}{Distribution Weibull}{Weibull}
\aeindex{توزيع كاوشي}{كاوشي}{Distribution Cauchy}{Cauchy}
\aeindex{توزيع أسي}{الأسي}{Distribution Exponential}{Exponential}
\aeindex{نسبة مخاطرة}{نسبة المخاطرة}{Hazard Rate}{Hazard Rate}
\aeindex{نسبة فشل}{نسبة الفشل}{Failure Rate}{Failure Rate}

\aeindex{توزيع رايلي}{رايلي}{Distribution Rayleigh}{Rayleigh}
\aeindex{توزيع منتظم}{المنتظم}{Distribution Uniform}{Uniform}
\aeindex{دالة متصلة}{دالة متصلة}{Continuous function}{Continuous function}

\aeindex{وسيط عينة}{وسيط العينة}{Sample's Median}{Sample's Median}
\aeindex{مدى عينة}{مدى العينة}{Sample's Range}{Sample's Range}
\aeindex{لفلفة}{لفلفة}{Convolution}{Convolution}
\aeindex{تحديدي}{تحديدي}{Deterministic}{Deterministic}
\aeindex{ثابتة بالدوران}{ثابتة بالدوران}{Rotation invariant}{Rotation invariant}
\aeindex{دالة توليد العزوم}{دالة توليد العزوم}{Moment Generating Function}{Moment Generating Function}
\aeindex{متنبأ}{متنبأ}{Predictor}{Predictor}
\aeindex{متنبأ خطي}{متنبأ خطي}{Linear Predictor}{Linear Predictor}
\aeindex{توقع شرطي}{التوقع الشرطي}{Conditional expectation}{Conditional expectation}
\aeindex{جمعية}{جمعية}{Additive}{Additive}
\aeindex{سلسلات ماركوف}{سلسلات ماركوف}{Markov chains}{Markov chains}
\aeindex{احتمالات التحول}{احتمالات التحول}{Transition probabilities}{Transition probabilities}
\aeindex{مصفوفة}{مصفوفة}{Matrix}{Matrix}
\aeindex{مبرهنة}{مبرهنة}{Theorem}{Theorem}
\aeindex{إستقراء}{الإستقراء}{Induction}{Induction}
\aeindex{متجه}{متجه}{Vector}{Vector}
\aeindex{أحادي}{أحادي}{One-to-one}{One-to-one}
\aeindex{تباديل}{التباديل}{Permutations}{Permutations}
\aeindex{مجموعة خالية}{المجموعة الخالية}{Empty set}{Empty set}
\aeindex{متوالية أو متتابعة}{متوالية أو متتابعة}{Sequence}{Sequence}
\aeindex{سلسلة أو متسلسلة}{سلسلة أو متسلسلة}{Series}{Series}
\aeindex{متنافية}{متنافية}{Mutually exclusive}{Mutually exclusive}
\aeindex{قابل للقياس}{قابل للقياس}{Measurable}{Measurable}
\aeindex{مختلفة}{مختلفة}{Distinguishable}{Distinguishable}
\aeindex{متساوية}{متساوية}{Equality}{Equality}
\aeindex{معادلة}{معادلة}{Equation}{Equation}
\aeindex{متباينة}{متباينة}{Inequality}{Inequality}
\aeindex{مفارقة}{مفارقة}{Paradox}{Paradox}
\aeindex{ما لا نهاية}{ما لا نهاية}{Infinity}{Infinity}
\aeindex{متباينة بونفيروني}{متباينة بونفيروني}{Bonferroni's inequality}{Bonferroni's inequality}
\aeindex{تقسيم}{تقسيم}{Partition}{Partition}
\aeindex{متباينة بونفيروني}{متباينة بونفيروني}{Bonferroni's inequality}{Bonferroni's inequality}
\aeindex{معاينة}{معاينة}{Sampling}{Sampling}
\aeindex{إرجاع}{الإرجاع}{Replacement}{Replacement}
\aeindex{احتمال الشرطي}{الاحتمال الشرطي}{Conditional probability}{Conditional probability}
\aeindex{قانون ضرب}{قانون الضرب}{Multiplication rule}{Multiplication rule}
\aeindex{قانون بايز}{قانون بايز}{Bayes' formula}{Bayes' formula}
\aeindex{فرص}{الفرص}{Odds}{Odds}
\aeindex{قانون احتمالات كاملة}{قانون الاحتمالات الكاملة}{Law of total probability}{Law of total probability}
\aeindex{حصرية}{حصرية}{Exhaustive}{Exhaustive}
\aeindex{متكافئة}{متكافئة}{Equivalent}{Equivalent}
\aeindex{محاولات}{محاولات}{Trials}{Trials}
\aeindex{نظرية}{نظرية}{Proposition}{Proposition}
\aeindex{مسألة نقاط}{مسألة النقاط}{problem of the point}{Problem of the point}
\aeindex{مسألة إفلاس}{مسألة الإفلاس}{ruin problem}{Ruin problem}
\aeindex{قانون  لابلاس للتعاقب}{قانون  لابلاس للتعاقب}{Laplace’s rule of succession}{Laplace’s rule of succession}
\aeindex{محاولات برنوللي}{محاولات برنوللي}{Bernoulli trials}{Bernoulli trials}
\aeindex{تكرار}{تكرار}{Recursion}{Recursion}
\aeindex{منفصلة}{منفصلة}{Discrete}{Discrete}
\aeindex{متصلة}{متصلة}{Continuous}{Continuous}
\aeindex{تطابق}{التطابق}{Matching}{Matching}
\aeindex{دالة توزيع احتمالي}{دالة التوزيع الاحتمالي}{Probability distribution function}{Probability distribution function}
\aeindex{تعدادي أو قابل للعد}{تعدادي أو قابل للعد}{Countable}{Countable}
\aeindex{دالة أوزان احتمالية}{دالة الأوزان الاحتمالية}{Probability mass function}{Probability mass function}
\aeindex{قيمة متوقعة}{القيمة المتوقعة}{Expected Value}{Expected Value}
\aeindex{وسط}{وسط}{Mean}{Mean}
\aeindex{وسيط}{وسيط}{Median}{Median}
\aeindex{عزوم}{العزوم}{Moments}{Moments}
\aeindex{تباين}{التباين}{Variance}{Variance}
\aeindex{تقاربية في المطلق}{تقاربية في المطلق}{Absolutely convergent}{Absolutely convergent}
\aeindex{عزم جمود}{عزم الجمود}{Moment of inertia}{Moment of inertia}
\aeindex{معادلات عودية}{معادلات عودية}{Recursive equations}{Recursive equations}
\aeindex{توزيع هندسي}{الهندسي}{Distribution Geometric}{Geometric}
\aeindex{توزيع فوق هندسي}{فوق الهندسي}{Distribution Hypergeometric}{Hypergeometric}
 \aeindex{توزيع ذي الحدين سالب}{ذي الحدين السالب}{Negative Binomial distribution}{Negative binomial}
\aeindex{فرضية ريمان}{فرضية ريمان}{Riemann hypothesis}{Riemann hypothesis}
\aeindex{دالة موبيوس}{دالة موبيوس}{M\"{o}bius function}{M\"{o}bius function}
\aeindex{مبرهنة قيمة القصوى-الدنيا}{مبرهنة القيمة القصوى-الدنيا}{minimax theorem}{Minimax theorem}
\aeindex{عدد اثناني}{عدد اثناني}{Binary digit}{Binary digit}
\aeindex{توزيع يول-سيمونس}{يول-سيمونس}{Distribution Yule-Simons}{Yule-Simons}
\aeindex{معلمة}{معلمة}{Parameter}{Parameter}
\aeindex{دالة كثافة احتمالية}{دالة كثافة احتمالية}{Probability density function}{Probability density function}
\aeindex{توزيع طبيعي}{الطبيعي}{Distribution Normal}{Normal}
\aeindex{مبرهنة نهاية المركزية}{مبرهنة النهاية المركزية}{central limit theorem}{Central limit theorem}
\aeindex{متماثل}{متماثل}{Symetric}{Symetric}
\aeindex{قانون أعداد الكبيرة}{قانون الأعداد الكبيرة}{Law Large numbers}{Law of Large numbers}
\aeindex{تصحيح عبر الاتصال}{التصحيح عبر الاتصال}{continuity correction}{Continuity correction}
\aeindex{توزيع إرلانج}{إرلانج}{Erlang distribution}{Erlang}
\aeindex{منتظمة التقارب}{منتظمة التقارب}{Uniformly convergent}{Uniformly convergent}
\aeindex{محور السيني}{المحور السيني}{The x-axis}{The x-axis}
\aeindex{محور الصادي}{المحور الصادي}{The y-axis}{The y-axis}
\aeindex{توزيع بيتا}{بيتا}{Distribution Beta}{Beta}
\aeindex{توزيع لوغاريتمي الطبيعي}{اللوغاريتمي الطبيعي}{Lognormal distribution}{Lognormal}
\aeindex{توزيع مشترك}{التوزيع المشترك}{Joint distribution}{Joint distribution}
\aeindex{توزيع هامشي}{التوزيع الهامشي}{Marginal distribution}{Marginal distribution}
\aeindex{مسألة إبر بوفون}{مسألة إبر بوفون}{Buffon’s needle problem}{Buffon’s needle  problem}
\aeindex{نصف العمر}{نصف العمر}{Half-life}{Half-life}
\aeindex{نوى}{النوى}{Nuclei}{Nuclei}
\aeindex{قيم سجلية}{قيم سجلية}{Record values}{Record values}
\aeindex{إحصاء تحليلي}{الإحصاء التحليلي}{Statistical analysis}{Statistical analysis}
\aeindex{إحصاء إستدلالي}{الإحصاء الإستدلالي}{Statistical inference}{Statistical inference}
\aeindex{شرطية}{شرطية}{Conditional}{Conditional}
\aeindex{جاكوبي}{جاكوبي}{Jacobian}{Jacobian}
\aeindex{مدى}{المدى}{Range}{Range}
\aeindex{تقابلية}{تقابلية}{Bijective}{Bijective}
\aeindex{محدد}{المحدد}{determinant}{Determinant}
\aeindex{توزيع طبيعي قياسي}{الطبيعي القياسي}{Distribution standard Normal}{Standard normal}
\aeindex{معكوس}{معكوس}{Inverse}{Inverse}
\aeindex{طريقة رفض}{طريقة الرفض}{Rejection Method}{Rejection method}
\aeindex{طريقة قطبية}{الطريقة القطبية}{polar Method}{Polar method}
\aeindex{تخفيض التباين}{تخفيض التباين}{Variance reduction}{Variance reduction}
\aeindex{متغيرات مضادة}{متغيرات مضادة}{Antithetic variables}{Antithetic variables}
\aeindex{مقدر}{مقدر}{Estimator}{Estimator}
\aeindex{تنازلية}{تنازلية}{Decreasing}{Decreasing}
\aeindex{تصاعدية}{تصاعدية}{Increasing}{Increasing}
\aeindex{موجه الاختلاف}{موجه الاختلاف}{Control variates}{Control variates}
\aeindex{معاينة الأهمية}{معاينة الأهمية}{Importance sampling}{Importance sampling}
\aeindex{قابلة للاستبدال}{قابلة للاستبدال}{Exchangeable}{Exchangeable}
\aeindex{نقطة سرج}{نقطة سرج}{Saddlepoint}{Saddlepoint}
\aeindex{مسار هاميلتوني}{مسار هاميلتوني}{Hamiltonian path}{Hamiltonian path}
\aeindex{خوارزمية الفرز السريع}{خوارزمية الفرز السريع}{Quick-sort algorithm}{Quick-sort algorithm}
\aeindex{خوارزمية بوكس-موللر}{خوارزمية بوكس-موللر}{Box-Muller algorithm}{Box-Muller algorithm}


\aeindex{تكرار}{تكرار}{Iteration}{Iteration}
\aeindex{تباين ثنائي}{التباين الثنائي}{Covariance}{Covariance}
\aeindex{معامل الارتباط}{معامل الارتباط}{Correlation's coefficient}{Correlation's coefficient}
\aeindex{حدود الدنيا-القصوى}{الحدود الدنيا-القصوى}{Maxima–Minima bounds}{Maxima–Minima bounds}
\aeindex{تباين عينة}{تباين العينة}{Sample variance}{Sample variance}
\aeindex{غير مرتبطة}{غير مرتبطة}{Uncorrelated}{Uncorrelated}
\aeindex{مفصّلة}{مفصّلة}{Quantized or Discretized}{Quantized or Discretized}
\aeindex{متعدد المتغيرات}{متعدد المتغيرات}{Multivariate}{Multivariate}
\aeindex{مبرهنة ليجندر}{مبرهنة ليجندر}{Legendre's Theorem}{Legendre's Theorem}
\aeindex{اختبار ويلكوكسن}{اختبار ويلكوكسن}{Wilcoxon test}{Wilcoxon test}
\aeindex{قيمة حرجة}{القيمة الحرجة}{Critical value}{Critical value}
\aeindex{متباينة كاوشي-شوارتز}{متباينة كاوشي-شوارتز}{Cauchy-Schwarz inequality}{Cauchy-Schwarz inequality}
\aeindex{توزيع كانتور}{توزيع كانتور}{Cantor distribution}{Cantor distribution}
\aeindex{تخيلية}{تخيلية}{Imaginary}{Imaginary}
\aeindex{برنستاين}{برنستاين}{Bernstein}{Bernstein}
\aeindex{ أحادية}{أحادية}{One-sided}{One-sided}
\aeindex{متباينة شيبيشيف}{متباينة شيبيشيف}{Chebyshev inequality}{Chebyshev inequality}
\aeindex{حدود تشيرنوف}{حدود تشيرنوف}{Chernoff bounds}{Chernoff bounds}
\aeindex{مبرهنة وايستراس}{مبرهنة وايستراس}{Weierstrass Theorem}{Weierstrass Theorem}
\aeindex{عملية بواسون}{عملية بواسون}{Poisson process}{Poisson process}
\aeindex{عدد عشوائي}{عدد عشوائي}{Random number}{Random number}
\aeindex{متباينة ماركوف}{متباينة ماركوف}{Markov's inequality}{Markov's inequality}
\aeindex{محددة بانتظام}{محددة بانتظام}{Uniformly bounded}{Uniformly bounded}
\aeindex{فرضية}{فرضية}{Assumption}{Assumption}
\aeindex{تزايدات مستقلة}{التزايدات المستقلة}{Independent increment}{Independent increment}
\aeindex{تزايدات ثابتة}{التزايدات الثابتة}{Stationary increment}{Stationary increment}
\aeindex{مدة إنتظار}{مدة إنتظار}{Waiting time}{Waiting time}
\aeindex{أنموذج اهرنفست}{أنموذج اهرنفست}{Ehrenfest model}{Ehrenfest model}
\aeindex{معادلات تشابمن-كولموجوروف}{معادلات تشابمن-كولموجوروف}{Chapman-Kolomogorov equations}{Chapman-Kolomogorov equations}
\aeindex{مسار عشوائي}{مسار عشوائي}{Random walk}{Random walk}
\aeindex{استبراء}{الاستبراء}{Ergodicity}{Ergodicity}
\aeindex{مستبرية}{مستبرية}{Ergodic}{Ergodic}
\aeindex{متناقصة بحدة}{متناقصة بحدة}{Strictly decreasing}{Strictly decreasing}
\aeindex{أنتروبيا}{أنتروبيا}{Entropy}{Entropy}
\aeindex{اعتلاج}{اعتلاج}{Entropy}{Entropy}
\aeindex{أنتروبيا}{أنتروبيا}{Entropy}{Entropy}
\aeindex{تشفير أقل ضجيج}{التشفير الأقل ضجيج}{Noiseless coding}{Noiseless coding}
\aeindex{مصفوفة مزدوجة العشوائية}{مصفوفة مزدوجة العشوائية}{Doubly stochastic matrix}{Doubly stochastic matrix}
\aeindex{نسبة نقل المعلومات}{نسبة نقل المعلومات}{Rate of transmission of information}{Rate of transmission of information}
\aeindex{محاكاة}{المحاكاة}{Simulation}{Simulation}
\aeindex{أعداد شبه عشوائية}{أعداد شبه عشوائية}{Pseudorandom numbers}{Pseudorandom numbers}
\aeindex{تبديل عشوائي}{تبديل عشوائي}{Random permutation}{Random permutation}
\aeindex{بذرة}{بذرة}{Seed}{Seed}
\aeindex{مولد}{مولد}{Generator}{Generator}
\aeindex{تكامل}{تكامل}{Integral}{Integral}
\aeindex{مشتقة}{مشتقة}{Derivative}{Derivative}

\aeindex{كانتور}{كانتور}{Cantor}{Cantor}
\aeindex{ستيرلينج}{ستيرلينج}{Stirling}{Stirling}
\aeindex{باسكال}{باسكال}{Pascal}{Pascal}
\aeindex{فيرما}{فيرما}{Fermat}{Fermat}
\aeindex{هيغنز}{هيغنز}{Huygens}{Huygens}
\aeindex{باناخ}{باناخ}{Banach}{Banach}
\aeindex{ريمان}{ريمان}{Riemann}{Riemann}
\aeindex{غاوس}{غاوس}{Gauss}{Gauss}

\aeindex{بواسون}{بواسون}{Poisson}{Poisson}
\aeindex{برنوللي}{برنوللي}{Bernoulli}{Bernoulli}
\aeindex{بايز}{بايز}{Bayes}{Bayes}
\aeindex{لابلاس}{لابلاس}{Laplace}{Laplace}
\aeindex{مندل}{مندل}{Mendel}{Mendel}
\aeindex{فون نيومان}{فون نيومان}{von Neumann}{von Neumann}
\aeindex{دي موافر}{دي موافر}{DeMoivre}{DeMoivre}
\aeindex{نيوتن}{نيوتن}{Newton}{Newton}


\aeindex{ليجندر}{ليجندر}{Legendre}{Legendre}
\aeindex{بوفون}{بوفون}{Buffon}{Buffon}
\aeindex{ستيلتجز}{ستيلتجز}{Stieltjes}{Stieltjes}
\aeindex{ماركوف}{ماركوف}{Markov}{Markov}
\aeindex{شيبيشيف}{شيبيشيف}{Chebyshev}{Chebyshev}
\aeindex{كينتشين}{كينتشين}{Khintchine}{Khintchine}
\aeindex{ليابونوف}{ليابونوف}{Liapounoff}{Liapounoff}
\aeindex{جالتون}{جالتون}{Galton}{Galton}

\aeindex{بوريل}{بوريل}{Borel}{Borel}
\aeindex{كولموجوروف}{كولموجوروف}{Kolmogorov}{Kolmogorov}
\aeindex{روس}{روس}{Ross}{Ross}
\aeindex{تشيرنوف}{تشيرنوف}{Chernoff}{Chernoff}

\aeindex{اهرنفست}{اهرنفست}{Ehrenfest}{Ehrenfest}
\aeindex{كولموجوروف}{كولموجوروف}{Kolmogorov}{Kolmogorov}
\aeindex{تشابمن}{تشابمن}{Chapman}{Chapman}
\aeindex{يانسن}{يانسن}{Jensen}{Jensen}

\aeindex{شانون}{شانون}{Shannon}{Shannon}
\aeindex{مسلّمة}{مسلّمة}{Axiom}{Axiom}
\aeindex{نتيجة}{نتيجة}{Corollary}{Corollary}

\aeindex{توزيع مثلث}{مثلث}{Distribution triangular}{Triangular}
\aeindex{توزيع كاي-تربيع}{كاي-تربيع}{Distribution Chi-squared}{Chi-squared}

\aeindex{تحليل توافقي}{التحليل التوافقي}{Combinatorial analysis}{Combinatorial analysis}
%%\aeindex{مجموعة خالية}{المجموعة الخالية}{Null set}{Null set}
\aeindex{حادث}{حادث}{Event}{Event}
\aeindex{اتحاد}{اتحاد}{Union}{Union}
\aeindex{تقاطع}{تقاطع}{Intersection}{Intersection}
\aeindex{حادث خاوي}{الحادث الخاوي}{Null event}{Null event}
\aeindex{حادث  مكمل}{الحادث المكمل}{Complementary event}{Complementary event}
\aeindex{تكرار نسبي}{التكرار النسبي}{Relative Frequency}{Relative Frequency}
\aeindex{بوكر}{البوكر}{Poker}{Poker}
\aeindex{بريدج}{البريدج}{Bridge}{Bridge}
\aeindex{تقسيم}{تقسيم}{Partition}{Partition}
\aeindex{خاصية اتصال}{خاصية الاتصال}{Continuity property}{Continuity property}
\aeindex{سلسلات}{سلسلات}{Runs}{Runs}
\aeindex{قسائم}{قسائم}{Coupons}{Coupons}
\aeindex{توقع}{التوقع}{Expectation}{Expectation}
\aeindex{وسط}{الوسط}{Mean}{Mean}
\aeindex{توزيع تراكمي}{التوزيع التراكمي}{Cumulative distribution}{Cumulative distribution}
\aeindex{أوقات ما بين الوصول}{أوقات ما بين الوصول}{Interarrival times}{Interarrival times}
\aeindex{محاكاة}{المحاكاة}{Simulation}{Simulation}
\aeindex{تحويل عكسي}{التحويل العكسي}{Inverse transform}{Inverse transform}
\aeindex{انحراف معياري}{الانحراف المعياري}{Standard deviation}{Standard deviation}
\aeindex{وراثة}{الوراثة}{Inheritance}{Inheritance}
\aeindex{نظرية لعب}{نظرية اللعب}{Game theory}{Game theory}
\aeindex{مفارقة سان بترسبرج}{مفارقة سان بترسبرج}{St.~Petersburg paradox}{St.~Petersburg paradox}
\aeindex{كينو}{كينو}{Keno}{Keno}
\aeindex{مفارقة برتران}{مفارقة برتران}{Bertrand's paradox}{Bertrand's paradox}
\aeindex{طبيعي قياسي}{طبيعي قياسي}{Standard normal}{Standard normal}
\aeindex{محدبة}{محدبة}{Convex}{Convex}
\aeindex{مقعرة}{مقعرة}{Concave}{Concave}
\aeindex{بيرسون}{بيرسون}{Pearson}{Pearson}
\aeindex{أرخميدس}{أرخميدس}{Archimedes}{Archimedes}
\aeindex{بدون ذاكرة}{بدون ذاكرة}{Memoryless}{Memoryless}
\aeindex{منوال}{المنوال}{Mode}{Mode}
\aeindex{مجموعة جزئية}{مجموعة جزئية}{Subset}{Subset}
\aeindex{لفلفة}{لفلفة}{Convolution}{Convolution}
\aeindex{إحصائيات الترتيب}{إحصائيات الترتيب}{Order statistics}{Order statistics}
\aeindex{صندوق بوليا}{صندوق بوليا}{Polya's urn}{Polya's urn}
\aeindex{نصف المدى}{نصف المدى}{Midrange}{Midrange}
\aeindex{سطح المستوى}{سطح المستوى}{Plane}{Plane}
\aeindex{خوارزمية}{خوارزمية}{Algorithm}{Algorithm}
\aeindex{انحرافات}{الانحرافات}{Deviations}{Deviations}
\aeindex{شوارتز}{شوارتز}{Schwarz}{Schwarz}
\aeindex{عملية تفرع}{عملية التفرع}{Branching process}{Branching process}
\aeindex{تنبؤ خطي}{التنبؤ الخطي}{Linear prediction}{Linear prediction}
\aeindex{عد}{العد}{Counting}{Counting}
\aeindex{نتيجة}{نتيجة}{Outcome}{Outcome}
\aeindex{احتمال}{الاحتمال}{Probability}{Probability}
\aeindex{تباديل}{التباديل}{Permutations}{Permutations}
\aeindex{توافيق}{التوافيق}{Combinations}{Combinations}


 \aeindex{كثيرات الحدود}{كثيرات الحدود}{Multinomial}{Multinomial}
 \aeindex{ذي الحدين}{ذي الحدين}{Binomial}{Binomial}

\RTLdblcol
\printindex{dico-arabic}{معجم المصطلحات العلمية  و الأسماء المستخدمة في الكتاب}
\LTRdblcol
\printindex{dico-english}{\hfill\LR{Mathematical terms and names used in the   book}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Malpivo as promised I post all the dictionnary obtained, and I have two things I want to do now...

Comment: @Malpivo as promised I post all the dictionnary obtained, and I have two things I want to do now...
1/ the first important, is that the indices are in twocolumn, and when the title is too long, it gives bad entry... I try to "solve" the problem with hand on the file of the arranged entries (the dico-english.ind file, for example), and change   \item \idxsechead{\begin{tabular}{c} Transition \hspace*{65pt} \hfill  \RLarabic{احتمالات} \\
  \hspace*{5pt}probabilities \hfill \RLarabic{التحول}\hspace*{5pt}   
\end{tabular}}, 
  \idxnopage{1}

Comment: instead of   \item \idxsechead{Transition probabilities\hfill \selectlanguage {arabic}\RL {احتمالات التحول}\selectlanguage {english}}, 
  \idxnopage{1}

Comment: This produces an entry in tabular form, which can be a beautiful macro with some latex work !! Any idea to do something like this with latex commands ?